# Outlook 2016 Crashing - Nothing I try solves it

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My manager's Outlook is constantly having issues. It very frequently stops responding and crashes. Sometimes it won't even open with various different error messages (or none at all, hanging at loading profile).

I have tried so many things to solve this:

- Upgrade to Professional Plus 2016 from 2013
- Switched from a 32-bit version to 64-bit
- Deleted profile and re-added
- Repaired with SCANPST
- Switched to and from cached exchange mode
- Upgraded from Windows 7 to 10 (which actually seemed to make the situation worse)
- Repaired the office installation
- I even switched the user to a different PC altogether at one point and the issue followed.

This user does have a very large inbox which is also being achieved. I've tried everything I can think of and just can't get it to work properly. I'm open to any and all suggestions anyone has about possible solutions. Any help would be appreciated.

**Current Setup:**

- Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 64-bit

Comment: Create a new login profile - setup outlook in that profile - should prevent crashing. If successful copy his data over to newly created profile

Answer (score 0):

Please check following information:

1. third-party add-ins

We can try opening Outlook in safe mode to see if the issue continues. Please exit Outlook, press Win key + R to open the Run command, type outlook.exe /safe and then press Enter. This helps eliminate whether the problem lies on any third party add-ins.

2. large size of mailbox

You may easily encounter performance issue if the mailbox is too large. Please archive mailbox to test the results.

3. Antivirus software

Antivirus software will integrate with Outlook client. Please check if you’ve installed any antivirus software on these computers. If yes, please temporarily close them to see if it helps.

4. SARA tool

If you are using Office 365 client, We could use Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant (SaRA) to run tests to resolve many different problems. For more details, please refer to [this link.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4098558/how-to-scan-outlook-by-using-the-sara-tool)

Please also have a look at Event Viewer when the issue occurs and see if any fault module will be recorded there.

You may also try TechNet forum as this issue has also been mentioned in this TechNet thread: 
[intermittent Outlook performance issues](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b3641ae8-0b82-42de-bbcf-965382641c78/intermittent-outlook-performance-issues?forum=outlook)
[Outlook 2010 keeps crashing](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/957f2bb1-c8ad-4732-8099-85b3f5f3d706/outlook-2010-keeps-crashing?forum=outlook)